# Commercial use of LaTeX templates

Tags: cv, documentclass-writing

I was wondering what are the licensing issues or the best way to know if certain templates allow for commercial use. I know the best way is to contact the original author but sometimes the sites don't provide contact info or the template is on a "list of best LaTeX resume templates".

I'm looking specifically for resume templates. However, if I can pay for LaTeX typesetters that would be the best case. Where would be the best place to find professional typesetters?

Comment: In TUG's site there's a [TeX Consulting and Production Services](http://www.tug.org/consultants.html) section that could be of interest for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Gonzalo's suggestion about consulting services is a good one.  two other places to ask for such help are [the texhax mailing list](http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/texhax) and the newsgroup [comp.text.tex](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/).

on [ctan](http://www.ctan.org/), packages will be accompanied by a readme file or other documentation that identifies the license.  you should look for "gpl" (gnu public license) or "lppl" (latex project public license) to be sure there are no strings attached.

packages in the category "curriculum vita" can be viewed [here](http://www.ctan.org/characterization/primary/document-types/curriculum-vita/).